# Change boot order on grub

Tags: 11.04, grub2, windows

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.04 inside windows 7 on my younger brothers laptop because he is slowly making the change over, at the moment when he turns the laptop on windows 7 is selected and I would like Ubuntu to be the first option, how do I change it?

Answer (score 2):

Install Grub Customizer.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Run it.

Click on Preferences (the wrench icon).
This is where you can choose which option should be selected by default when you boot.

Comment: Is that the same as boot-manager?

Comment: Be careful with PPAs, they're unsupported, so don't automatically assume they're safe.

Comment: @zookalicious It's similar. I believe that Grub Customizer may be simpler to use, though...

Answer (score 1):

you can rename files in `/etc/grub.d/` ??_linux should be renamed with number less than ??_os-prober

then run `sudo update-grub2`